# Trouble Parsing data using Zapier Poll URL to Google Sheets

Tags: json, parsing, google-sheets-api, zapier

My goal is to use Zapier's Poll URL utility to check this API: http://acleddata.com/api/acled/read for new data, and then update a google sheet.

It is able to find and download the data correctly:
[image: screenshot of test data]

However, I'm not sure how to tell Zapier to parse "Data", which is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary represents a row in a spreadsheet and key represents a column.

You can see here that Zapier is not parsing it correctly when I need to map my google sheet columns to values I want to put in each cell. [image]

I suspect the issue is in the edit options section of the poll, but I'm not really sure what to put where
[image]

Thoughts are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a "Key" of "data" to select the list of records from the poll.

Comment: I suspect you are correct. The issue is what format the key should be in. Any thoughts?